# Copy one git branch with an extra commit to another that is one behind

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit

I have the following git structure (Numbers denote commits):

```
  _ 1 _ 2 _ 3 _ 4  (Branch mainline)
_|
 |_ 1 _ 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 (Branch Test)
```

Thus, Test has one extra commit than mainline does. I basically need to copy over that commit to mainline. How do I do that?

So my end state should be:

```
  _ 1 _ 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 (Branch mainline)
_|
 |_ 1 _ 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 (Branch Test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One option:

   ```
   git checkout mainline
   ```

   and then any of:

   ```
   git merge test
   git rebase test
   git reset --hard test
   git cherry-pick test  #probably not really recommended
   ```
2. Another option:

   ```
   git branch -D mainline
   git checkout -b mainline test
   ```

I'm sure there are many more.